# Split a string by two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Firstable i want to match if a string has the following format: `$abc #xyz` or `$abc .xyz`.

> The **abc** and **xyz** mean only **alphanumeric** string.

If it's matched then i need to extract the first `$abc` and the last `#xyz`, all that using pure javascript and maybe regex.

The pattern is in the following order:

1. Dollar Sign
2. Unlimited alphanumeric string
3. space
4. a hash or point
5. Unlimited alphanumeric string

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So the pattern is dollar sign, three alphanumeric characters, space, hash, three alphanumeric characters?

Comment: So you don't want to have `.xyz`? Why do you say the first and the last? I thought the string can only exists of theses two "words".

Comment: @ionesomeday the pattern is a dollar sign, and unlimited alphanumeric characters, space, hash or point, and unlimited alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
/^(\$[a-zA-Z\d]+) ([#.][a-zA-Z\d]+)$/
```

Explanation:

```
^              Start of line.
(              Start capturing group.
\$             Literal dollar sign.
[a-zA-Z\d]     Any letter in a-z or A-Z, or any digit.
+              One or more of the previous.
)              End capturing group.
<space>        Literal space.
(              Start second capturing group.
[#.]           Either a number sign or a period.
[a-zA-Z\d]+ 
)              End second capturing group.
$              End of line.
```

Example usage:

```
> var s = '$abc #xyz';
> s.match(/^(\$[a-zA-Z\d]+) ([#.][a-zA-Z\d]+)$/);
["$abc #xyz", "$abc", "#xyz"]
```

Comment: If you make the capture groups include `\$` and `[#.]` then it is exactly what the OP wants I think.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
if(str.match(/^\$[a-z0-9]+ (#|\.)[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
    var parts = str.split(' ');
}
```

**Update:** Obviously there a various ways to achieve this. There is not *the one* regular expression. If you make use of capture groups, you can extract the strings even in one step ([like Mark showed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640309/split-a-string-by-two-characters/4640333#4640333)).

Comment: You need to escape the `.` (or else use `[#.]` where escaping is not required).